# Tidymodels. step_impute_linear(), can it be used when every column contains NAs

Tags: r, tidymodels

My data contain >100 columns and every one of them contains `NA`'s, and when I try to use `step_impute_linear()` it returns a mistake

*Warning message:*

> ```
>       There were missing values in the predictor(s) used to impute;
>       imputation did not occur.
> ```

Can, I, somehow make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll need to use at least two steps of imputation.

- First you will need to choose some variables to impute with something very simple, like the median or mode. I would choose the variables with *lower* rates of missingness for this.
- Next you can choose some variables to impute with linear models, using **only complete variables** (the ones you imputed first with, say, the median). I would choose variables with *higher* rates of missingness for this, I think.

Here is an [example analysis where I took](https://juliasilge.com/blog/baseball-racing/) this approach:

```r
bb_rec <-
  recipe(is_home_run ~ launch_angle + launch_speed + plate_x + plate_z +
    bb_type + bearing + pitch_mph +
    is_pitcher_lefty + is_batter_lefty +
    inning + balls + strikes + game_date,
  data = bb_train
  ) %>%
  step_date(game_date, features = c("week"), keep_original_cols = FALSE) %>%
  step_unknown(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors(), one_hot = TRUE) %>%
  step_impute_median(all_numeric_predictors(), -launch_angle, -launch_speed) %>%
  step_impute_linear(launch_angle, launch_speed,
    impute_with = imp_vars(plate_x, plate_z, pitch_mph)
  ) %>%
  step_nzv(all_predictors())
```

If you want to try out different strategies for types of imputation, I suggest [setting up workflowsets](https://juliasilge.com/blog/star-trek/) and test on resampling folds.